# How do I pass more parameters to a UIAlertAction's handler?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Is there any way to pass the array "listINeed" to the handler function "handleConfirmPressed"? I was able to do this by adding it as a class variable but that seemed very hacky and now I want to do this for multiple variables so I need a better solution.

```
func someFunc(){
   //some stuff...
   let listINeed = [someObject]

   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Destructive, handler: handleConfirmPressed))
   presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func handleConfirmPressed(action: UIAlertAction){
  //need listINeed here
}
```

Comment: You could also write a method to return your `listNeed` object and use that method.

Comment: @Zhang I don't see how that would be any different from assigning it to a class variable

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way is to just pass a closure to the `UIAlertAction` constructor:

```
func someFunc(){
    //some stuff...
    let listINeed = [ "myString" ]

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Destructive, handler:{ action in
        // whatever else you need to do here
        print(listINeed)
    }))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If you really want to isolate the functional part of the routine, you can always just put:

```
handleConfirmPressedAction(action:action, needed:listINeed)
```

into the callback block

A slightly more obscure syntax, that would retain the feel of a function both in passing it to the completion routine and in the callback function itself would be to define `handleConfirmPressed` as a curried function:

```
func handleConfirmPressed(listINeed:[String])(alertAction:UIAlertAction) -> (){
    print("listINeed: \(listINeed)")
}
```

and then you can `addAction` using:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Destructive, handler: handleConfirmPressed(listINeed)))
```

Note that the curried function is shorthand for:

```
func handleConfirmPressed(listINeed:[String]) -> (alertAction:UIAlertAction) -> () {
    return { alertAction in
        print("listINeed: \(listINeed)")
    }
}
```

Comment: But then how do I change this line: alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Destructive, handler: handleConfirmPressed))?

Comment: Just like in the example code I give.  If you're unfamiliar with Swift and it's closure/block syntax, dig out the Apple Swift book and go through it.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean now. I was hoping I didn't have to use a closure and I could just pass in a method, but this way works excellently. Thanks!

Comment: In swfit 4 It should be     func handleConfirmPressed(listINeed:[String]) -> (_ alertAction:UIAlertAction) -> () {
    return { alertAction in
        print("listINeed: \(listINeed)")
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easier.

```
class MyUIAlertAction: UIAlertAction {
    var params: [String: Any] = [:]
}

func someFunc(){
    //some stuff...
    let listINeed = [ "myString" ]
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    
    let action =  MyUIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .destructive, handler:{ (action: UIAlertAction) in
        if let myaction = action as? MyUIAlertAction {
            let listINeed = myaction.params["listINeed"] as? [String] ?? []
            // whatever else you need to do here
            print(listINeed)
        }
    })
    action.params["listINeed"] = listINeed
    
    alert.addAction(action)
}
```